# How to create a network from nodes and boundaries?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have a table of nodes (points) and i wish to route between the points. Its my understanding that i first need to build a pgrouting compatible topology (graph ?) that connects all the nodes using "source" and "target" fields.

I was just wondering what tools i can use to generate this topology ? assign_vertex_id doesn't seem to work.

I'm using postgis on a postgresql database.

edit: The nodes are basically points in free space (water), so there aren't any lanes as such. The only constraints are land mass boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use pgRouting you need a graph network. The nodes alone won't help. If you can define links between your points that will give you `source` and `target` as well as the `cost` for this link, then pgRouting algorithms should work.

Eventually this article is useful: http://www.georeference.org/doc/shortest_path_over_land.htm

Comment: This is exactly what im talking about, what kind of tools can i use to built that graph ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what was called for was a vector based feature topology such as ascii street routing segments where graph is linear delineation of street routing, so point as beginning or end node of street segments.

Comment: I guess my question is, given my table of points how do i generate a connected graph that pgrouting can route through ?

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the answer. Routing between points is not an exercise in pure abstraction, topology does not refer to a graph that is programmatically generated by an  algorithm. The routing needs a street layer and the points would have to be functionally a part of the street layer as segment end points so that they are intrinsically and topologically a part of the route and an object that could be read by pgrouting.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm pretty new to this. What exactly do you mean by street layer ?.

Comment: Ascii art: o-----o-------o , it has two roads which have total of 3 nodes (start or end points) and one them is shared so that  means that you can go from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 on this network, nut not from 3 to 1 (wiyhout going to 2 ) .. those lines arent used for routing, else than creating it and counting cost for edge(road). Now if you have for example harbors and you want to calculate cost between them , you need to create all possible vector lines (roads) between them to get cost and topology